# New data frame after function is empty

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I prepare a function to have a temporary dataframe, but whent i apply this function on my old dataframe , the temporary dataframe is empty. How can i solve this ?

I tried this code :

```r
data_a <- as.data.frame(cbind(pop=c("a1","b2","c3","d4","d5"),
                         PA1=c(1,40,430,4330,43330),
                        PA2=c(2,50,530,5330,53330)))

perm_all <- function(dat,vname,loc1, loc2){
  popu <- dat["vname"]
 locci_1 <- sample(dat["loc1"], replace = F)
 locci_2 <- sample(dat["loc2"], replace = F)
 data_a_1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(popu, locci_1, locci_2))
  return(data_a_1)
 }

data_3 <- perm_all(dat= "data_a",vname="pop",loc1="PA1",loc2="PA2")
```

I've tried to convert the data_a with

```r
data_a <- as.matrix(data_a)
```

and

```r
 popu <- sample(dat[,1], replace = F)
```

but they didn't work too

Thank's :)

Comment: I think you called your `data_a` as a **string**. Do you try remove the string?
`data_3 <- perm_all(dat=data_a, vname="pop", loc1="PA1", loc2="PA2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are maybe multiple issues. First, when you have created your data frame, be aware that data.frame function family treat string as a factor by default. It may be not what you want.

Then @NURAIMIAZIMAH is right, your function needs a data frame to work properly, so :

```
data_3 <- perm_all(dat= data_a,vname="pop",loc1="PA1",loc2="PA2")
```

is a good start.

Moreover, you give value to vector like `vname`, `loc1` and `loc2`. But you only use the name of these objects in your function, because you forgot to remove quotation mark.

```
perm_all <- function(dat,vname,loc1, loc2){
  popu <- dat[vname]
  locci_1 <- sample(dat[loc1], replace = F)
  locci_2 <- sample(dat[loc2], replace = F)
  data_a_1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(popu, locci_1, locci_2))
  return(data_a_1)
}
```

Now your function should work, but maybe not in the way you would like to. Because there won't be any permutations in your `data_3` table. If you look carefully, the type of return of this part of the code `dat[loc1]` is a data frame. You certainly want a vector to permute your data, so you have to subset your data frame like this : `dat[,loc1]`.

This code below should do what you expect.

```
data_a <- as.data.frame(cbind(pop=c("a1","b2","c3","d4","d5"),
                              PA1=c(1,40,430,4330,43330),
                              PA2=c(2,50,530,5330,53330)))

perm_all <- function(dat,vname,loc1, loc2){
  popu <- dat[vname]
  locci_1 <- sample(dat[,loc1], replace = F)
  locci_2 <- sample(dat[,loc2], replace = F)
  data_a_1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(popu, locci_1, locci_2))
  return(data_a_1)
}

data_3 <- perm_all(dat= data_a,vname="pop",loc1="PA1",loc2="PA2")
```

See you.